# How to modify this regular expression to not match a non-breaking space?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm using [John Gruber's regular expression](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls) to try to match URLs in a document.

I've represented the regular expression in Python like this:

```
URL_PATTERN = re.compile(ur'(?i)\b((?:https?://)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?\xab\xbb\u201c\u201d\u2018\u2019]))')
```

This is a modified version of a version found [here](https://gist.github.com/uogbuji/705383).

This works well in most cases except for documents which contain non-breaking spaces. In Python I see this represented as `\xc2\xa0`.

Here is an example string that I'm attempting to parse; hopefully the characters will paste in tact:

```
Go to https://example.com to log in.
```

If I print just that string in Python, I get:

```
In [100]: string
Out[100]: 'Go to\xc3\x82\xc2\xa0https://example.com\xc3\x82\xc2\xa0to log in.'
In [101]: URL_PATTERN.search(string).groups()
Out[102]: ('https://example.com\xc3\x82\xc2\xa0to', None, None, None, None)
```

The string that I am attempting to match against is an `str`, not `unicode`.

How can I modify this regular expression to **not** match this character? I've tried putting `\xc2\xa0` into the `^` negated character class near the end of the regex, but it still matches the URL with the space characters.

Comment: You might have to add the `\u00A0` to the negated character classes where you have `[^\s]`. Also, testing for Unicode characters in Python 2.x is a bit cumersome since you often need to `encode` / `decode`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you add your comment as an answer so I can accept it? Your suggestion worked but I also had to add `\u00c2` as well. I also add to specify "unicode" mode by using `re.compile(ur'(?iu)...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid matching URLs with non-breaking spaces you need to add `\u00A0`  to the negated character classes `[^\s]` and pass the `re.U` flag when compiling the pattern:

```
URL_PATTERN = re.compile(ur'(?i)\b(https?://(?:[^\u00A0\s()<>]+|\(([^\u00A0\s()<>]+|(\([^\u00A0\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\u00A0\s()<>]+|(\([^\u00A0\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\u00A0\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?\xab\xbb\u201c\u201d\u2018\u2019]))', re.U)
                                                 ^^^^^^              ^^^^^^              ^^^^^^                           ^^^^^^            ^^^^^^                  ^^^^^^                                                            ^^^^
```

Comment: I also had to add `\u00c2`

Comment: It stands for `Â`, which is often a corrupted non-breaking space.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's not *corrupted*. It's how non-breaking space is [encoded in UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Encodings).

Comment: @Piotr: In the localization industry, when a customer gets a translation with `Â` instead of a space in the text, they would say "Why did you deliver corrupted translations"? *It is corrupt text from the point of view of a regular user.*

Comment: Replying to an ancient comment, but to avoid someone else wondering, `0xc2` is not how `U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE` is encoded in UTF-8. The actual encoded value is the sequence `0xc2 0xa0`. (all UTF-8 bytes with the most significant bit set are part of a multi-byte sequence). The confusion arises when the text is interpreted as ISO-8859-1 (or -15), where, out of coincidence `0xc2 0xa0` becomes `Â` _followed_ by a non-breaking space.